# Como hago un filtro para validar datos html?

Tags: php, html, filtro

quisiera saber como puedo conseguir que en una pagina html, en un input, que cuando un usuario ponga un codigo html como una reedireción a otra pagina por ejemplo, mi servidor lo filtre.

Sin usar ningun tipo de libreria.

Comment: Lo más cercano a lo que pides es `strip_tags` :  http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: @Xerif voy a diferir de tu opinión, ya que `strip_tags` no es seguro. [Aquí he explicado por qué](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130461/29967) con argumentos. Oriol, PHP tiene varios tipos de filtros de saneamiento, [indicados aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/filter.filters.sanitize.php). O quizá en tu caso lo que habría que hacer sería bloquear las redirecciónes... No hay una norma de seguridad mágica que te proteja contra todo, se trata de aplicar en cada caso la norma de seguridad más adecuada.

Comment: @A.Cedano  Buenas, tienes razón.