# Ignorar tags HTML que están en una tabla SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

Tengo que mostrar en una tabla **html** una columna de una tabla que tiene este formato:

> `<p>contenido</p>`

Y al mostrarlo en el html me lo muestra tal cual `<p>contenido</p>`, pero necesito que se muestre solo `contenido`sin el tag de parrafo

Comment: ¿Qué manejador de base de datos usas: MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, Postgresql ...?

Comment: Postgresql para esta consulta en concreto

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que la función `strip_tags` te puede funcionar:

Según el manual en php.net:

> strip_tags — Retira las etiquetas HTML y PHP de un string

Uso:

`string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )`

Esta función intenta devolver un string con todos los bytes NULL y las etiquetas HTML y PHP retirados de un str dado. Se utiliza la misma máquina de estado de retirado de etiquetas que la función fgetss().

Parámetros:

*str*

> El string de entrada.

*allowable_tags*

> Se puede usar el segundo parámetro opcional para especificar cuales
>   etiquetas no deben ser retiradas.

ejemplo :

```
<?php
 $text = '<p>Párrafo.</p><!-- comentario --> <a href="#fragmento">otro   texto</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Permite <p> y <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

Resultado :

```
 Párrafo. Otro texto
 <p>Párrafo.</p> <a href="#fragmento">Otro texto</a>
```

**Fuente:**

Aquí [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php) puedes encontr más información y ejemplos

Comment: Dependiendo de como lo quiera hacer, si directamente en SQL o luego ya en la propia lógica del php, he encontrado esto en SO, que tal vez le pueda interesar [Strip HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/457725/7064040) , aunque sinceramente, considero que tu respuesta le irá mejor que la mía.

Comment: Pero atención, `strip_tags` **no es una función segura**. Sirve para este tipo de usos sencillos. Ahora bien, si se trata de reemplazar otro tipo de contenido, te pueden inyectar código fácilmente mediante esta función (ver algunas notas del Manual de PHP y también [la primera parte de esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130461/29967)).

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente haya una forma mejor de hacerlo, pero lo primero que me viene a la mente es:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(T1.CAMPO_1,'<p>'),'</p>') AS campo_sin_eqtiquetas, ....
FROM TABLA T1, ....
WHERE .....
```

Espero que fuera lo que estabas buscando.

El funcionamiento de `REPLACE()` en SQL es bastante sencillo:

`REPLACE(campo,'string')`
Elimina la cadena del resultado del campo

> "*Esto es un string eliminado*" = "*Esto es un  eliminado*"

`REPLACE(campo,'string','cadena2')` Sustituye la primera variable por la segunda

> "*Esto es un string sustituido*" = "*Esto es un cadena2 sustituido*"

En ambos casos se puede utilizar `AS` para dejar el nombre del campo más legible, porque en tu caso por ejemplo, mostraría algo tal que así:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(T1.CAMPO_1,'<p>'),'</p>')
```

Comment: Más o menos, pero también los caracteres "raros" me los saca por ejemplo una o con tilte me la muestra así: `&oacute;`

Comment: Cabe destacar que el archivo html es un html.twig con lo que no puedo poner codigo php.