# Evitar inyección de código en formularios

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, mysqli

Tengo un formulario que luego es usado para generar páginas mediante un plantilla. Cuando el usuario rellena los datos, estos tienen que ir a la base de datos, y luego en la página, se cargan y se imprimen mediante un "echo".

Mi pregunta es, ¿Es suficiente con usar `strip_tags()` antes de almacenar las variables? Les dejo una muestra para que me ayuden a mejorar la seguridad.

```
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$desc = strip_tags($_POST['desc']);
$date = strip_tags($_POST['date']);
$winners = strip_tags($_POST['winners']);
$img = strip_tags($_POST['img']);
$lang = strip_tags($_POST['lang']);
```

Luego, directamente almaceno las variables creadas en la base de datos.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Usa consultas preparadas tambien.

Comment: `strip_tags` no es recomendable ni para proteger la información que vas a presentar en pantalla ([leer esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130461/29967)) ni para prevenir la Inyección SQL. Para lo primero deberías usar [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php) y para lo segundo consultas preparadas.